# How do I check if there are other hard drives with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With my program I want to check if there are other hard drives connected to the computer, and then I want the program to print the names of those hard drives (like `C:`)

The hard drive I'm now working on is called `C:`, but I also have a drive connected to the computer called `D:`.

How do I let my program find out all the other hard drives connected?

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32api
import win32file
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    return [drive for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings() if
                re.match(r"^[A-Z]+", drive) and win32file.GetDriveType(drive + ":" + "//") == win32file.DRIVE_FIXED]
```

You can use this to find all fixed drives and not CD drives or USB drives